# Can't call method from gem (Twilio-ruby), appears to be looking in my controller, how to scope this properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have the following line in my gemfile and have done a `bundle install`:

```
gem 'twilio-ruby'
```

I have the following code based on the examples for twilio-ruby gem:

```
class TwilioEntriesController < ApplicationController

  def process_message

    # init client 
    @account_sid = 'REMOVED'
    @auth_token = 'REMOVED'
    @from_number = '+14159675278'

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)

    # send response
    @client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => @from_number,
      :to => '+REMOVED',
      :body => 'Hey there!'
    )

    render :result, :layout => ''
  end  

end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
uninitialized constant TwilioEntriesController::Twilio
```

It appears that Ruby is looking for the "Twilio" class inside of the "TwilioEntriesController", which is where the call is originating from.  It should be calling the method from the correct class ("Twilio") - What gives?

How can I call static methods on the Twilio class as described by the twilio-ruby documentation?

Answer (score 2):

This is most definitely caused by Twilio gem not being required properly. Double-check that `bundle list` includes twilio-ruby, and that bundler is properly setup in your rails app.

Comment: Be sure to restart the server (rails s) after modifying them Gem file, otherwise rails s will not see your gem file changes - this was the problem for me.

Comment: @Tronathan: Wow, I can't believe I forgot to do this. +1

Answer (score 1):

When a constant is looked up, Ruby will walk `Module.nesting`, which is `[TwilioEntriesController]` in your case. For each entry, it will search:

1. In the module itself
2. In the modules included in that entry (going recursively)
3. For classes, in the superclass (also going recursively)

If the module can't be found anywhere, an exception is raised, and the first module it used to search is used in the exception message. So your error also means that there is no Twilio constant at top-level, probably because of a missing call to `require`.

(There's no such thing as a static method in Ruby; there are only instance and class methods — the latter of which can be seen as instance methods too, depending on your point of view.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `::Twilio` on line 10.

That's like calling an absolute path from root (/foo/bar) for Modules & Classes.

Comment: Adding :: gives a better response: `uninitialized constant Twilio`, it appears that the gem isnt properly included... if i add 'require twilio-ruby', i get `no such file to load -- twilio-ruby` .. could the gem be broken? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

Comment: Had to restart rails server to pick up changes to Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't built a Rails app in awhile but I think you can solve this problem by putting

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
```

at the top of your controller file. There may be a more appropriate central place to put all your requires in a modern Rails app though so consult documentation for the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but ran into same error recently.
Add this to your file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'
```